# Etwas leinwand finden

Tags: idiom, dialect, austrian

Was heißt das?

> Das finde ich leinwand.

Beispiele:

- Das finde ich leinwand. Das heißt für mich, dass er nicht nur für sein kleines Ego lebt.
- Andy Warhol - Superstar! Joseph Beuys - kein Einwand! Doch Albrecht Dürer's Hände, die wo beten, find ich Leinwand! Sie beten noch immer in jedem Schlafzimmer!

**Update**

Sorry, ich habe nicht gesehen: auf der Webseite mit dem Liedtext gibt es schon eine Erklärung (https://www.verunsicherung.de/diskografie/songs/nie_wieder_kunst.html):

> „find ich Leinwand“ ist ein Wortspiel mit dem österreichischen Begriff „leiwand“, welcher soviel wie „grossartig“ bedeutet.

Ich lasse die Frage hier hängen für die, die das brauchen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es heißt nicht *»leinwand«* sondern *»leiwand«* (ohne n) und ist ein Adjektiv, wird also kleingeschrieben: [Eintrag auf Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/leiwand). Das Wort kann in Wien (und nur dort) als Synonym für *»toll, super, spitze«* verwendet werden. Da es sich um ein Dialektwort handelt, und es für Dialekte keine verbindliche Rechtschreibung gibt, findet man vielfach auch die Schreibweise *»leiwound«,* die der tatsächlichen Aussprache deutlich näher kommt als *»leiwand«.*

Wie die meisten Adjektive kann es attributiv (*a lauwanda Hawara = ein toller Kerl*), prädikativ (*des Bia is leiwand = das Bier ist spitze*) und adverbial (*des Bia schmeckt leiwand = das Bier schmeckt sehr gut*) verwendet werden.

Zur Herkunft kann ich leider nicht mehr beitragen, als auf Wiktionary steht:

> #### Herkunft:
>
> nicht eindeutig geklärt, vermutlich von *Leinwand* wegen des hohen Wertes des Leinens auch als Aussteuer. Im Mittelalter: *linwat* ‚Leinengewebe‘, später an das Wort *Gewand* angeglichen.
> oder: 1432 erhielt das Wiener Bürgerspital, in dem damals bereits mit Leinen gehandelt wurde, das Braurecht. Das dort auch ausgeschenkte „Leinwandbier“ genoss einen guten Ruf. „des is leiwand“ bedeutete, dass der bezeichnete Gegenstand so gut sei wie das Bier.

Gegenwörter sind *Schas* (maskulines Substantiv, standarddeutsch: der Furz, der Darmwind) und *Oasch* (maskulines Substantiv, standarddeutsch: der Arsch), wobei *oasch* häufig auch als Adjektiv verwendet wird. Auch *schas* gibt es als Adjektiv, wird allerdings selten verwendet, und wenn, dann nur attributiv (*Die schas/oasch Bremsn woa schuld am Unfoi = die miese/schlechte Bremse war schuld am Unfall*), nicht aber prädikativ oder adverbial (korrekt: *des Bia is oasch = das Bier ist mies/schlecht; des Bia schmeckt oasch = das Bier schmeckt nicht gut* aber falsch: <del>*des Bia is schas; des Bia schmeckt schas*</del>)

[image: FÜR LEIWAND GEGEN OASCH]

Das Wort ist kein standarddeutsches Wort, auch kein österreichisches Wort<sup>1</sup> sondern ein Wort aus einem Wiener Dialekt. In Wien werden in unterschiedlichen sozialen Schichten  unterschiedliche Dialekte gesprochen, *»leiwand«* kommt nicht in all diesen Dialekten vor. Es wurde und wird vor allem von Arbeitern verwendet, während es von wohlhabenderen Personen kaum verwendet wird.

Auch außerhalb Wiens ist dieses Wort nicht besonders häufig anzutreffen. Ich bin in Graz geboren und aufgewachsen (ca. 200 km südsüdwestlich von Wien) und hörte das Wort zum ersten Mal in dem Lied *»Schifoan«* von Wolfang Ambros (1976, damals war ich 13). Textzitat aus dem Refrain:

> Wöh Schifoan is des **leiwaundste** wos ma sich nur vurstelln kann.
> <sub>Weil Skifahren das Größte ist, was man sich vorstellen kann.</sub>

Auch jetzt, wo ich in St. Pölten lebe (ca. 60 km westlich von Wien), höre ich dieses Wort kaum. In Wien ist es aber nach wie vor in Gebrauch.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Den Begriff *»österreichisch«* (in Bezug auf Sprache) sollte man ohnehin vermeiden. Das wird in [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/71783/1487) ausführlicher behandelt.</sub>